# Why onOptionsMenuClosed() method in android is not called?

Tags: java, android, menu

I am a newbie in Android programming, while I was reading through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsMenuClosed(android.view.Menu)) on the **Menus**, I came across certain methods that are called at specific instant of times.

Among them one method is [**`void onOptionsMenuClosed (Menu menu)`**], it is called whenever the options menu is being closed i.e either by :

- the user canceling the menu with the back/menu button.
- or when an item is selected).

However, while Logging and Toasting messages it doesn't get called, Why so?

```
@Override
    public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
        Log.e("MainActiviy", "onOptionsMenuClosed() method is called when option menu is close");
        Toast.makeText(this, "onOptionsMenuClosed() method is called when option menu is close",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an issue about Android Studio. DOn't use the Android Studio tag

Comment: Many of the menu-related methods are from Android 1.x/2.x. The options menu was replaced by the action bar, and some of the old menu-related methods are no longer used. I would not expect `onOptionsMenuClosed()` to be called when the action bar is being used.